# Compute these expectations for non-independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, independence

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5$ be five random variables independent, identically distributed and valued in $[0,1]$, and denote $f$ their density function.

Then denotes four another random variables defined by : $\nu_{1j}= 2 - X_1 - X_j$ for all $j \in \{2, \dots, 5 \}$. It is clear that these four random variables are not independent.

I am trying to compute two quantities :

$$A= \mathbb{E}[\min_{2\leq j \leq 5}\{ \nu_{1j} \} ] \text{  and  } B= \mathbb{E}[\max_{2 \leq j \leq 5}\{ \nu_{1j} \} ]$$

I know how to compute, for $j \in \{2, \cdots, 5\} :$

$$ \mathbb{E}[ \nu_{1j}  ] = \int_{0}^2 (2-x) g(x) \ \mathrm{d}x:=C$$

where $g(x)= f \star f(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) f(y-x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ is the density function of $X_1 + X_j$.

I can conclude that I have :

$$ A \leq C \leq B$$
but **I would like to have better explicit inequalities**, **or even completely compute $A$ and $B$**. However I am quite stuck since I can't use transfer theorem for the $\nu_{1j}$ are not independent. Any clues on how to proceed ? If that's helping I'm fine considering the same setup but with only $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and

$$A^*= \mathbb{E}[\min_{2 \leq j \leq 3}\{ \nu_{1j} \} ] \text{  and  } B^*= \mathbb{E}[\max_{2 \leq j \leq 3}\{ \nu_{1j} \} ]$$

Any help is welcomed !

Comment: We have $$\min_{2\leq j \leq 5} V_{1j} = 2-X_1- \max_{2\leq j \leq 5} \{X_j\}$$ and so the expectation is $$2 - E[X_1] - E[ \max_{2\leq j \leq 5} \{X_j\}] = 2 - E[X_1] - \int_0^1(1-P[Max \leq x])dx = 1-E[X_1] + \int_0^1 P[X\leq x]^4dx$$